# Risk of a single Doc with a dozen arrays containing thousands of small objects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Can the write operations on a single doc break when many users are online?

There will be ~12 such arrays, each with tens of thousands of such objects. Write operations would be:

- increment(+1) for the count field of existing objects based on currency and activity (stay, sports...),
- add an entire new object when it's a new currency and country,
- update an existing object, eg: increment(-1) or price change.

*Note: all data is displayed at once on a single page*.

```
stayCount [
{price: "15", count: 2, country: "USA", currency: "USD"},
{price: "15, count: 3, country: "UAE", currency: AED},
{price: "25", count: 5, country: "USA", currency: USD}
]
sportsCount [
{price: "15", count: 1, country: "Germany", currency: EUR},
{price: "49, count: 6, country: "UAE", currency: AED},
{price: "49", count: 8, country: "France", currency: EUR}
]
```

Asking because of the one write max per Doc per second rule.

Comment: Just wondering but why not create a subcollection within the document instead?

Comment: @Ryan so you mean adding the count property in an object in the subcollection? If so, it makes my COUNT() function based on all objects and on a single array and on a currency much more complicated. I actually wonder if the simple count will really be heavy on the Doc with real risk of “crash”.

Comment: What I mean is by having a subcollection called 'stayCount', 'sportsCount', etc. Then every element will be its own document and any operations would be performed on a seperate document.